# Loading icon does not reappear when content in iframe is changed

Tags: javascript, iframe, loading

I have an iframe that shows a graph, controlled by a form. I already included in the script to show a loading gif when the iframe is loading. However this gif only appears when the iframe is loaded for the first time. However, when I make changes in the form to display the data I want to see, the iframe reloads to show a new graph, but the 'loading' gif does not reappear. How can I fix this? this is the code I already have for the loading gif:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="divLoading">
    <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="divFrameHolder" style="display:none"> 
<iframe src="grafiek.php" width="800" height="400" name="grafiek" onload="hideLoading()" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" align="middle" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a hideLoading in the onload attribute of your iframe, your loading is hidden after the first loading of the iframe. Then you change the iframe but like the loading icon is out of the iframe, it does not shown anymore. Try to show it again when you change the iframe.

You actually do:

- load iframe, show loading icon for the first time
- when iframe is shown, hide loading (hideLoading method in the onload attribute)
- change the iframe source: the icon is not shown anymore and so does not appear

You should do:

- load iframe, show loading icon for the first time
- when iframe is shown, hide loading (hideLoading method in the onload attribute)
- change the iframe source: just before changing the iframe, show again the loading icon

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but can you specify how to do this? I am not that experienced so a bit of sample code would be very handy..  Thanks in advance!